Why should the normal force equal the weight of an object when the surface on which it stands is flat?
In the context of newtonian mechanics, I am investigating whether the normal force exerted by the surface upon an object must always equal the weight of the object mg (i.e., the gravitational force applied by the object and earth upon one  another, as per the 3rd Law), provided that the surface on which the object stands is flat.
Now considering the object and earth as a non-accelerating single system, I understand that there are two pairs of forces we are dealing with here (please do correct me if I'm wrong about that)
1-) The gravitational pull exerted upon each other under the universal law of gravitation, which we call the weight of the object.
2-) The normal force, again, exerted upon each other that arises due to the contact between the object and earth.
If we were to draw the free body diagrams of the object and earth seperately, in each case, we would see the gravitational pull mg and the normal force N such that these two have opposite directions.
Now my question is how do we know (or if we know) that these two forces, mg and N are equal in magnitude: Both can be considered internal forces of a system which are ultimately "cancelled out" by their counterparts and I think we take for granted that their directions must be opposite which makes intuitive sense. But how we can conclude that they are equal in magnitude is beyond me: The magnitude N could be a fraction of that of mg or even greater than that, could it not?

Your question implies that you don't fully accept Newton's 3rd law.  If so, what is it about the 3rd law that doesn't make sense to you?

@DavidWhite For an elementary physicist this is not necessarily a bad question. I could 100% see a world in which someone missed out on the explanation given by the professor or in which it was simply never given - that’s the case for my learning experience years ago.

@DavidWhite Newton's Third law is not the reason the weight and normal force here are equal; these forces do not constitute a action-reaction pair

There are many cases where they are not equal.

If you consider the Earth and the object as a single system that is not accelerating in an inertial frame, and the object and the Earth are not moving with respect to each other (implying neither is accelerating), then the two forces that act on the object (say) must have the same magnitude to cancel out, otherwise the object would fly off the Earth. (The other two forces only affect the Earth.) However, even in that scenario, the motion of the Earth-object system as a whole is unchanged; in this context, "the motion of the system as a whole" means the motion of it's center of mass.

Since you already know each force is "cancelled out" by their counterpart, how could they not be of equal magnitude and opposite direction? Once you accept (or observe!) that they cancel each other, "same magnitude, opposite direction" is just a reformulation.

Note to people who commented on my question:  I'm not saying that the OP is asking a bad question.  I'm also not trying to identify what is an action-reaction pair.  I'm trying to get the OP to be somewhat more specific in the hope that me and others can identify a mis-concept.

Consider a pen sitting on your desk. Is the pen accelerating? If not, then the net force acting on the pen must be zero. OK, so what forces are acting on the pen that add up to zero?

Gravity attracts the pen toward the center of the Earth.
Contact force between the pen and the desktop stops the pen from falling to the center of the Earth.

Any others?
If there's only two force vectors, and if their sum is zero, then how could their magnitudes not be equal?

That is when we are able to observe the pen not acclerating, if an alien were to study us and he was asked to predict if the pen would accelerate or not he would need to know wheter teh force by which its pushes on desk is equal to ist weight which in turn relies on knowing its acceleration isnt it circular reasoning?

@MohdSaad, The person in my thought experiment can see the pen and, can see the desk and the room. They can see that the position of the pen (in the room coordinate system) does not change with time. That's enough information to infer zero coordinate acceleration. If I ask the same question of some other person who is not allowed to see the pen or the room, then they will not be able to answer unless I give them some different clues.

I see and that is my exact problem they would not be able to, but I have always seen newtonian mechanics and much of physics in general as deterministic so I know the weight of pen and I decide to put it on the table , I cannot know in advance by this argument if the table breaks or pen flies in air or it remains there.

You state that we consider the object and the earth as a non-accelerating single system.  By Newton's first (or second) law, if a system has zero acceleration then the net force on the system is zero.  If there are only two forces in the system, then they must be equal and opposite and thus add to zero.
But now, we could relax the conditions a little.  Let's say that the "object" is really two half-masses, one on top of the other, with the top one supported by a spring, and we allow the top half-mass to oscillate up and down a little bit.  In this case, the normal force (acting on the bottom half-mass) will vary sinusoidally about a value equal to the weight of both masses.  You could construct other similar scenarios, say maybe an unbalanced windmill, or a static version involving magnets.
But the bottom line is that if the forces on any object do not sum to zero in a non-accelerating frame, some kind of acceleration will result.

But the forces add up to zero in my scenario as well: F net of the system = mg1 - mg2 + N1 - N2 = 0  That is to say: the weight and normal force are indeed cancelled out but not by each other but by their reciprocals. What am I failing to see here?

I think I see it now, I have always mentioned that the net force acting upon the system must be zero but in that case the net forces acting upon each individual object within the system must be zero as well and when considered seperately, both the earth and the object have mg and N as the only forces acting upon them which must add up to zero  hence the result.

Yes, in the case of multiple masses, you can draw as many "free-body" diagrams as there are masses to get a set of independent equations.   When we consider the earth as a mass, it's kind of confusing because we don't really think of objects as having a gravitational pull on the earth.  But technically they do.  When we consider the object and the earth separately, $N_1-mg1=0$ and $N_2-mg2 = 0$.

In fact, if you draw a free body diagram of the object AND the earth, by convention you aren't supposed to (or don't need to) include the internal force pair $N_1$ and $N_2$.  Your result would be that $mg1 = mg2$, although its confusing to write it that way because it implies that the earth mass and the object mass are equal, which they aren't.  But the net forces are.

@David06 "But the forces add up to zero in my scenario as well [...] What am I failing to see here?" - if you consider each object separately, then you cannot add up all four forces because they don't all act on the same object. The two forces that don't act on one of the objects don't contribute to its motion whatsoever. If you consider both objects as a single system, then the zero net sum of internal forces is a statement about the center of mass (COM) of the system; internally the individual components might be accelerating, but in such a way so that the COM is not.

Consider a block at rest on a table. $mg$ and $N$ are being exerted on it by the Earth and table, respectively. Why should $mg=N$?
$mg$ and $N$ are directed antiparallel for a flat surface level with the ground - they point in opposite directions. So the total force is $F=mg-N$ (note that by setting $mg>0$ we establish “down” as the positive direction; the choice is arbitrary). Given that the block is at rest, i.e. it is not in motion and is not accelerating in any direction, the total force must be zero, so $F=0$.
Then, it is easy to solve $mg-N=0$ to obtain $mg=N$. QED.

What if the block isn’t at rest?
Consider a block dropped onto a table. Over some short time $\mathrm{d}t$, the table will exert a force $F$ such that $F\mathrm{d}t=p$, where $p$ is the block’s momentum upon contact with the table. This is equivalent to saying that the table must put a force on the block to slow it down to rest, which makes sense.
But all the while, another force, $mg$, is acting to keep the block accelerating downwards. Intuitively, if $F=N<mg$, the block will continue to accelerate downwards because the net force is pointed downwards, and it will not stop for the table. This is called the table breaking. If we assume instead that $F=N>mg$, then the net force will be directed upwards, and the block will slow down. Eventually the block will come to rest and $N$ will equal $mg$ once again.

What if the table is lowered slowly?
If you put an acceleration on the table that’s less than one Earth gravity, then the block will stay in contact with it the whole time. When it does, the block must also be accelerating downwards at the same rate, which means that the total force on it, $F=mg-N$, must be positive but less than $mg$; clearly $N<mg$ in this case.

Conclusion: $N=mg$ if and only if the table and block are at rest. The normal force indeed changes if the table or block are in motion, but in the case that you describe (the block at rest on a table) the normal force has to necessarily cancel the gravitational force exactly.

We don't require that the block and table are at rest, we just require that they are not accelerating. It it fundamentally impossible to discern between being "at rest" and moving with a constant velocity. For two objects moving with constant relative velocity, each one sees themselves at rest and the other one as moving, and neither is wrong. Different observers will disagree whether the block and table are at rest or not, but all inertial observers will agree that N=mg, regardless of what constant velocity they see the block and table as having.

But it is my understanding that F = mg1 - mg2 + N1 - N2 as I have stated in my post, the way I see it is we are dealing with two pairs of reciprocal forces within the system which indeed must add up to zero granted the system is not accelerating (which we assume to be the case) Why do you say that the total force consists of mg and N alone and not consider the counterparts of these forces?

@NuclearHoagie I would have specified that but I think that when talking about elementary physics specifying reference frames/relative acceleration is a little unnecessary.

@David06 $N$ is the reaction force of $mg$; they are counterparts. If you want to talk about other action/reaction pairs, you certainly can, but they all sum to zero, shouldn’t they?

@controlgroup You say "N is the reaction force of mg" I think this is exactly what I am failing to see. How is that the case? By the universal law of gravitation both the object and earth exert upon one another mg do they not? It has nothing to do with whether they come into contact or not whereas the normal force N occurs due to them coming into contact which must "create" a new pair of forces, namely,  N1 and N2

You could also consider the block falling onto the ground (i.e. the gravitating object, the Earth) instead of a table. After that point, though, I will recommend that you just consider that a two-body system, because going any deeper will start to make things tedious for you. Normal force is, for the record, how scales work to measure mass, and since scales obey the simpler laws, we can assume that the simpler laws hold for other things too.

@controlgroup I don't think N is the reaction force of mg, strictly speaking at least. See my comment on Mariano G's answer. I think I have resolved the issue I was having with this.

I believe the source of confusion was that @David06 was drawing a FBD of the object PLUS earth but including normal forces $N_1$ and $N_2$.  Thus, as he said, he ended up with the equation $mg1 - mg2 + N_1 - N_2 = 0$.  If you ONLY consider that equation then it only says that $N_1 = N_2$.  Which isn't the complete answer.

Ohh, yeah that’ll do it. I’m glad that the confusion is cleared up then.

I think I have clarified the issue I was having so I am writing this answer to my own question.
I say "...considering the object and earth as a non-accelerating single system,..." But what I was missing is the fact that if the system is not accelerating i.e. the net force on the  system is zero, so also must be the net forces on each individual object within the system, namely, the object and Earth. (That's because not only is the system as a whole non-accelerating, but also each individual object.)
The net force acting on the system is given by Fnet(system) = mg1(exerted by Earth upon the object) - mg2(exerted by the object upon Earth) + N1(exerted by Earth upon the object) - N2(exerted by the object upon Earth)
Now we know that mg1 and mg2, together with N1 and N2 constitute two action-reaction pairs (by the 3rd Law) which ultimately cancel out and make the net force on the system equal zero. However this equation does not reveal whether mg and N are equal in magnitude.
There comes into play the FBD's of each individual object: The net force of the object is given by Fnet(object) = mg1 - N1 and we know the LHS of the equation equals zero because the object itself is not accelerating. Which gives us 0 = mg1 - N1 which means mg1 = N1 which was to be shown.

The magnitude of the normal force can be measured by a scale between the mass and the ground.
As mentioned by another answers, if the body is not accelerating, there is a downward force on the mass with the same magnitude. That downward force is what we call force of gravity.

Just use Newton's 1st law. If the object is stationary on horizontal ground, then the sum of all forces acting on it must be zero according to Newton's 1st law. With only gravity and then the normal force from the floor acting in the object, then we have:
$$\sum F=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n-w=0
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n=w.$$
Ergo, they must be equal.
But note, only in this very specific case. The normal force is not in general equal to the weight. That is only the case in the special case we have set up with no acceleration and horizontal ground and isolated from other forces.
